# Create div and add style

Tags: json, dojo

I have one big div with id="elements" and I load from JSON file new elements objects and I need that for every element create new div inside elements ( elements div should contain lot off smaller divs, for every element one small div ). How to place this small divs inside this big div one behind another ? How to add this small divs a class style ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Dojo (since you have the dojo tag):

```
var div_elements = dojo.byId("elements");

dojo.forEach(json_data.items, function(item) {
    dojo.create("div", { "class":"whatever " + item.classNames }, div_elements);
});
```

Of course, you can put anything as the class for your div.  I just provided an example.  In the second argument to `dojo.create`, you pass in a hash containing all the properties you want that `div` to have.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new DOM element like so:

```
var childDiv = document.createElement('div');
```

Then add to the outer div like so:

```
var insertedElement = div.insertBefore(childDiv, null);
```

You would then keep creating childDivs as you iterate over your JSON data, and inserting them into the div Node as above.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

json_data = 'Hey';

$('#elements').append('<div class="in_elements">' + json_data + '</div>');

});

</script>

<div id="elements">

</div>
```

Test it

Comment: Please explain what exactly you want to do and give some source

Answer (score 1):

There a simple jQuery functions for that:

```
var box= $("#elements");
    // create elements
    for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
        var t = $("<div class=\"element\" id=\"item_"+i+"\">"+items[i]['text']+"</div>");
        box.append(t);
    }
```

That's what you where looking for?